# Trying to generate random password characters into a file

Tags: shell, scripting, password

I want to generate `100` files with `100` random passwords in `/mnt/mymnt/passwords` using a script creating some directories.

Even if i try to use `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 30 | head -n 1 > some_random_file.txt` the process just does not stop, anyone has any idea why?

Comment: @JeffSchaller uh yeah, fold, sorry and "tr" too

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it worked but it stopped inserting passwords after the first file, and I don't get why

Comment: `On a Side note:` Next time Give a try to [crunch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/crunch.1.html). That would be much easier than writing a script but If you are into learning rather than achieving some task, writing script is Cool :)

Comment: Using openssl to generate the random value may help. Take a look at "openssl rand -hex 32" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do
   cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '_A-Za-z0-9' | head -c${1:-32} > Password$i
done
```

Comment: Too many hyphens in the tr character set: `tr -dc '_A-Za-z0-9'` and you can replace the letters and numbers with a character class: `tr -dc '_[:alnum:]'`

Comment: yours is wrong i think

Comment: /dev/urandom uses su or sudo, so the script needs to be run as such. Works on my computer running Debian 9. I see it can be condensed. Thanks glenn!

Comment: Fixed my error. Can now be ran as normal user also. Forgot cat and one pipe, memory not as good as I thought. :( @C.Cristi

Comment: I believe that your shell syntax is off a bit.  Look at adding some parentheses and replacing the last ``|`` with ``>``.

Comment: Script is somewhat working now, creating passwords and files but files are empty, thanks for pointing out its faults. @G-Man

Comment: Working the way it should now! @C.Cristi

Comment: I hope you're not going to run that with `sudo` on a multiuser production system. Or at least, if you do, that you run it in a private directory where no-one else can create files.

Comment: This works now. @C.Cristi